# What does Word.DocumentProperties.security mean?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am developing an Office Add-In for Word and so I am using OfficeJs.

I have this code, that should execute some stuff if the Word document is in read-only mode.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
   var prop = context.document.properties;
   prop.load("*");

   return context.sync().then(function () {
       if (prop.security && prop.security !== 0) {
           // do some stuff
       }
   });
});
```

I do not understand the meaning of `prop.security`. I tried to change the Word document mode to read-only, but the value of `prop.security` doesn't change immediately, even after reloading the Add-In. Sometimes `prop.security`'s value is `0`, other times is `8`.

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.documentproperties?view=office-js#security) only says: `Gets the security of the document`, but doesn't explain the meaning of those values.

Could anyone help me and explain how Word.DocumentProperties.security works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 3**:

A developer at Microsoft has found official documentation. It is part of the Open Office XML standard, specifically the DocSecurity element: [ISO/IEC 29500-1:2016](https://www.iso.org/standard/71691.html) (Download the zip file and search the PDF in side for "DocSecurity".) There is some further information about how Microsoft has implemented it here: [2.1.1713 Part 1 Section 22.2.2.7, DocSecurity](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fopenspecs%2Foffice_standards%2Fms-oi29500%2Ff0f1a882-555d-4c3d-b751-4fe6cd1011af&data=04%7C01%7Crickki%40microsoft.com%7C6b2fff3211fa48d97a7508d6df9dfa2e%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636942266938399582%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C-1&sdata=M%2FIcG5bJwklZGMn5EiXRHkAdfmTKGmCUCbrBxuHK8Lo%3D&reserved=0) . This documentation confirms that the list in UPDATE 2 below is correct. (So, ignore the "(Probably)"s.) Also, it shows that the 16 values listed are the only possible values.

**UPDATE 2**:

Based on the OP's comment below, here is the updated list of values. I have not been able to verify the ones marked "(Probably)" but based on the pattern, I'm very confident that they are correct. This is not necessarily complete. There may be values higher than 15.

```
0 = File on disk is read/write
1 = Protect Document: File is encrypted and requires a password to open
2 = Protect Document: Always Open as Read-Only
3 = Protect Document: Both #1 above and #2
4 = File on disk is read only
5 = Both #1 above and #4 above
6 = Both #2 and #4
7 = (Probably) All of #1, #2, and #4
8 = Protect Document: Restrict Edit to read-only
9 = Both #1 and #8
10 = Both #2 and #8
11 = All of #1, #2, and #8
12 = (Probably) Both #4 and #8
13 = (Probably) All of #1, #4, and #8
14 = (Probably) All of #2, #4, and #8
15 = (Probably) All of #1, #2, #4, and #8
```

**UPDATE**: 
It is not powers-of-2 and some of the values are connected with the **Protect Document** options in the File menu. Here are the values I've been able to discover:

```
0 = File on disk is read/write
1 = Protect Document: File is encrypted and requires a password to open
3 = Protect Document: Both #1 above and #6 below
4 = File on disk is read only
5 = Both #1 above and #4 above
6 = Protect Document: Always Open as Read-Only
8 = ?
```

Note that some of the Protect Document options disable Script Lab, so I can't test if they have a `wdPropertySecurity` value. I *think*, but haven't tested, that they would block any add-in, so an add-in would never return these values if they exist.

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
I've gotten a bit of information from a developer on the Word team. The `BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertySecurity)` value refers to the properties of the document *as a file on disk*. When you set the view mode to read-only, you are not changing the access to the file on disk, so the wdPropertySecurity value should not change. If it was `0`, it should stay `0`. The developer discovered the meaning of `0` and `4`. Since you've seen `8`, it looks like these are powers-of-2, so there's probably a `2` as well. This is what the developer reports:

```
0 = read/write
2 = ?
4 = read only
8 = ?
```

I'll add to this if I discover more. In the meantime, can you provide the exact steps that lead to getting an `8`?

Comment: Thank you Rick for your answer. I got an 8 when I Restrict Edit to read-only. I also discovered that when file is Always Open Read Only, security'value is 2. When file is Encryption + RestrictEdit, security is 9. When file is AlwaysOpenReadOnly + RestrictEdit, security is 10. When file is Encryption + AlwaysOpenReadOnly + RestrictEdit, security is 11. My Word document is stored in Azure Storage Emulator.

Comment: @EstevaoLuis. Thanks, I'll include your discoveries in the documentation.